# Definition of Singleton

Tags: java

The definition of singleton is to ensure a class only has one instance, and provide a
global point of access to it.

What is the meaning of

```
global point of access
```

here?

Comment: What do you think it means? What is _point of access_? How do you access a class/instance? What is _global_?

Answer (score 1):

It means that you can access the **same** single instance of your class from anywhere in your code without the need to initialize it each time (hence global).

Answer (score 0):

A global point of access means that this is a accessible from anywhere in an application (hence global). It is a public class with a public method in a package that is visible to all other packages.

Answer (score 0):

It would be the static method used to return the static instance of the class.

e.g.

```
class Singleton {

 private static Singleton instance; //the instance of this

 private Singleton(){} //lock constructor

 static Singleton getInstance() { //this is the point of access (I think)
   if (instance==null) instance=new Singleton(); //instantiate if needed.
   return instance;  
 }

}
```